# Can TreeMap be used to retrieve all key/value pairs above a given key value?

Tags: java, treemap

I have a piece of code that maintains a map of revisions done to samples with a given ID:

```
private Map<Long, SampleId> sampleRevisionMap = new HashMap<>();
```

While maintaining this, other threads can call in to get all changes made since the given revision number. To find the relevant IDs I do

```
public Set<SampleId> getRevisionIDs(long clientRevision) {
    return sampleRevisionMap.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(k -> k.getKey() > clientRevision)
                .map(entry -> entry.getValue())
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

In short, give me all values with key above a threshold.

is there a better way to do this employing an ordered map, i.e. java.utils.TreeMap?

Comment: Note that TreeMap is not synchronized. You are saying all threads can hop in to read the key/value pairs. You need to use `Map syncMap = Collections.synchronizedSortedMap( treeMap )`

Comment: Also note that the return map from `synchronizedSortedMap` will be mutable and other threads can modify it while one thread is iterating over it (or the values of its tail map). The iterating thread must synchronize on it which iterating over it. See the [`synchronizedSortedMap` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSortedMap-java.util.SortedMap-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by calling [`tailMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#tailMap(K)):

```
public Collection<SampleId> getRevisionIDs(long clientRevision) {
    return sampleRevisionMap.tailMap(clientRevision).values();
}
```

The above includes the value mapped to `clientRevision` as well. If you want everything above it, use `clientRevision+1` instead.

Comment: @BjarkeMoholt Actually, it should not be declared as type TreeMap.  It should be declared as type SortedMap or NavigableMap.  Always refer to the type representing the contract rather than the implementation.